# change chrome extension's icon on some certain websites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to my chrome extension change icon when there is certain string contained in current tab's url. I am a newbie on chrome extension design, so I test some basic message sending functions first. But the setIcon function does not work, and no error message shows in extension.
Here is my manifest file:

```
{"permissions" ["identity","identity.email","tabs","activeTab","http://34.204.12.200:5000/"],
"short_name": "React App",
"name": "React Extension",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": {
"default_popup": "index.html",
"default_title": "React Ext",
"default_icon" : {
  "512": "icon1.png",
  "512": "icon2.png"
} 
},
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
  { 
   "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
   "js": ["contentScript.js"]
 }
],
"version": "1.0"
}
```

my contentScripts:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
             action: 'updateIcon',
             value: true,
         });
```

my background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
if (msg.action === "updateIcon") {
    if (msg.value===false) {
        chrome.pageAction.setIcon({
            tabId: sender.tab.id,
            path: {"512":"icon2.png"}
        });


        //alert(msg received)
    } else {
        //tabId: sender.tab.id,
        chrome.pageAction.setIcon({
                    tabId: sender.tab.id,
                    path: {"512":"icon1.png"}});
    }
}
});
```

both my icon1 and icon2 are 512*512, and they are in same directory as manifest.json.
my chrome extension icon always show icon2, it seems that both my background.js and contentScript not working. Does anybody know why?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-setIcon): tabId is a required property.

Comment: already modified, but still not working

Comment: Your manifest defines only browserAction, which you can also use to change the icon, see the documentation for chrome.browserAction.setIcon.